# GridView auto fit images

Tags: android, gridview

im trying to get images displayed in a GridView and get the columns automatically set, so far I've had to manually set the number of columns which is not what i want to do as this will affect how big the images are on different sized screens. I ahve tried setting it to auto_fit but it only displays 2 columns in the middle of the screen. This is what im trying to achieve: (Each red square represents an image)

[image]

then when turned to landscape mode i want the columns to auto fit so that its all even.
Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Experiment with the GridView attributes, specifically `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` and `android:stretchMode`. The following works for me:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"    
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Comment: Brilliant. I had auto_fit, but was missing columnWidth. After I added that, things started working beautifully.

Comment: I had everything except the columnWidth param, which is mandatory to have anything out of 2 columns

Comment: I have the same exact XML but still the GridView shows only 2 columns!

Comment: @ΕГИІИО If you don't specify columnWidth you will get 2 columns by default, as looking at GridView's source code would tell you. You can use my solution (specified here) for those cases.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why someone voted down the answer above me (so I voted it up again): I had to solve a similar problem programatically (with a GridView of ImageView children). Some code removed for clarity:

```
    int iDisplayWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels ;

    iImageWidth = iDisplayWidth
        / iNumberOfColumns ; 
    gridview.setColumnWidth( iImageWidth );
    gridview.setStretchMode( GridView.NO_STRETCH ) ;    
    /* wrap_content in the xml file is supposed to do this, but it didn't seem to work */
```

Best regards,

Piesia

Comment: Why is NO_STRETCH better than STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH for stretch mode?

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to measure the width programmatically, so you won't end up with a hard-coded column width:

[Android: How does GridView auto_fit find the number of columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912922/android-how-does-gridview-auto-fit-find-the-number-of-columns/7874011#7874011)