# Android: How does GridView auto_fit find the number of columns?

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to understand better how `Gridview` works, in particular `auto_fit`.
Here is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
/>
```

And it works fine with a series of six thumbnails (48*48 pixels).  In portrait mode, it displays one row, six columns.

[image: with]

What I don't understand is why the line `android:columnWidth="60dp"` is necessary, because [auto_fit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:numColumns) is expected to find the right number of columns.
Without the line `android:columnWidth="60dp"`, it displays a grid 3 rows and 2 columns.

[image: without]

Here is the `ImageAdapter` class:

```
package com.examples.HelloGridView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_1, R.drawable.ic_2,
            R.drawable.ic_3, R.drawable.ic_4,
            R.drawable.ic_5, R.drawable.ic_6
    };
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Looking at the GridView source, it is clear that setting the padding and the height on your ImageView will not help you at all. When a column width is not specified, it just chooses a preset number of columns (2):

```
    private void determineColumns(int availableSpace) {

    ...

    if (mRequestedNumColumns == AUTO_FIT) {
        if (requestedColumnWidth > 0) {
            // Client told us to pick the number of columns
            mNumColumns = (availableSpace + requestedHorizontalSpacing) /
                    (requestedColumnWidth + requestedHorizontalSpacing);
        } else {
            // Just make up a number if we don't have enough info
            mNumColumns = 2;
        }
    } else {
        // We picked the columns
        mNumColumns = mRequestedNumColumns;
    }

    if (mNumColumns <= 0) {
        mNumColumns = 1;
    }

    ...
```

The solution is to measure your column size before setting the GridView's column width. Here is a quick way to measure Views offscreen:

```
public int measureCellWidth( Context context, View cell )
{

    // We need a fake parent
    FrameLayout buffer = new FrameLayout( context );
    android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new  android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    buffer.addView( cell, layoutParams);

    cell.forceLayout();
    cell.measure(1000, 1000);

    int width = cell.getMeasuredWidth();

    buffer.removeAllViews();

    return width;
}
```

And then you just set the GridView's column width:

```
gridView.setColumnWidth( width );
```

Comment: It's a conceptual example of solving the problem. Since you need to know the actual width, I've included a code snipet that measures it.

Comment: @Nishant  You can use setColumnWidth() right after you use setAdapter() on your GridView.

Comment: What is view in measureCellWidth( Context context, View cell)?

Comment: You wanna measure the column width by code. So cell is the view which you plan on putting in that column, so in the end the column width will be equal to cell's width.

Comment: You simply need to add gridView.setColumnWidth( width ); after you set the adapter on the gridview

Comment: @Vaiden can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957819/gridview-and-it-is-images-are-not-automatically-fit-for-all-the-screen-sizes-in

Comment: @Nikson this seems to be exactly the same issue

Comment: I have applied lot of codes but nothing is worked for me ... can you help me in this

Answer (score 7):

According to the [android:numColumns documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:numColumns)

> `auto_fit` Display as many columns as possible to fill the available space.

So if you insert `ImageView`s with

`padding` set to `zero`

`margin` set to `zero`

`layout_width` set to `wrap_content`

`layout_height` set to `wrap_content`

The gridView should contain the maximum possible number of children

---

**Keep in mind** Your ImageViews maybe are getting scaled (:

Comment: I have added the ImageView code.  The margin is not set, I'll see if it's what I missed.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't necessarily believe the Android documentation. Some places still have example code which uses pre-1.0 functions!

Comment: Timmmm gets it, the accepted answer shows that setting dimensions and layout options on ImageView does nothing in this case; the Gridview component is not particularly thorough with its calculations. Usually it just defaults to 2.

Answer (score 3):

This may help someone...
You need to find width size manually. Based on the width size you can set column

```
        float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
        int number = getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int columns = (int) ((float) number / scalefactor) / 2;
        if (columns == 0 || columns == 1)
            columns = 2;
        gridView.setNumColumns(columns);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that I usually know how wide I want my columns to be. Either I know the size of my pictures or I let the user determine that size. Therefore i can just set the width in my Activity:

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int gridSize = 50 * Integer.parseInt(mySettings.getString("gridSize", "3"));
    gridview.setColumnWidth(gridSize + 10);
```

Thats all . . .

Greetings from Lucerne,
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

"wrap_content" works like word wrap does for text editors - if the image cannot fit into the last column size, the image flows to the next row. However, if you set the numcolumns attribute  to a number then the grid may stretch/adjust the columns (stretchModde is another property that you may want to use in conjunction).

ps - although you have ticked the answer, would be glad to know if this helped.