# How to know Gridview last colum in every row android

Tags: android, gridview

In getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method of an adapter how to know if position is reflecting the last column of the row ?

For example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Let say this is GridView then element 3,6 and 9 are last column of row 1,2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the grid, how many columns you have:

```
int numColumns = ((GridView) viewGroup).getNumColumns();
```

after that you could use the '%' operation:

```
boolean isLast = (position % numColums) == 0;
```

Comment: No the columns are different in different devices
GridView is having the following properties:

        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

Comment: Then use 'int numColumns = ((GridView) viewGroup).getNumColumns();' and after that you can do the '%' operation

Comment: But getNumColumns() will return -1 i.e AUTO_FIT  if the Grid has never been laid out.

Comment: This could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912922/android-how-does-gridview-auto-fit-find-the-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Call mGridView.getNumColumns() in getView() of the adapter.This will give the number of columns a row can have. Once we have that we can easily know which position is going to be the last column of the row.