# How to set the column size of a gridview in custom grid adapter?

Tags: android

How to set the column size of a gridview  in custom grid adapter? I have to set the column size according to the maximum value in an item in list which passed into the adapter? please suggest me an option?

Comment: You'll have to create a custom layout for it.

Comment: i did it. i parsed a json array and stored values in a List. I have to set these  images according to these values in each position But the problem is the column value change according to the json array we get.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912922/android-how-does-gridview-auto-fit-find-the-number-of-columns