# Grid View auto number of columns depending on screen size

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I am using Gridview and I want to show some pictures in it. I want my grid view to look good in all sizes of screen. I mean I am developing my app for different android devices such as Samsung Galaxy Grand which is normal device , Samsung tab 4 which is 7 inch device and in the end Samsung tab 10 which is 10 inch device.

So I want my grid view to take auto number which looks good on device such as I want 4 column on Samsung Tablet 10 inch and with same ration 3 or two in 7 inch and same like this on other devices.

So what I have done so far is simple thing , made an array for Images and set adapter to the gridview that is simple code and that has nothing o do with my problem so I am not sharing that code What I have with its desing is in xml so my xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So please help me out in this problem. How can I make the number of columns to auto fit the screen width. ??

Comment: Take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7874011/2308720

Comment: I know this acepted answer but I dont  know how is he working

Comment: I've tried you code and it works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @Alexandr on which devices you have tested my code?

Comment: Lenovo s960. I've just change size of columnWidth to smaller one and checked on emulator as well. What is expected result of tour demo?

Comment: i wanted it to show  in good possible way , I mean In samsung galaxy grand screen size 5 inch , it should be 2 column and in 7 inch device it should be 3 column and in 10 inch device it should be 4 column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89358/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-alexandr).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use different number of columns for different screen sizes - override value in different `values` folder (small, normal, large, xlarge), see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Example:

**Activity or fragment:**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="@integer/column_count"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
    />
```

**Item:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

**values/integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="column_count">2</integer>
</resources>
```

**values-large/integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="column_count">3</integer>
</resources>
```

**values-xlarge/integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="column_count">4</integer>
</resources>
```

Comment: yeah the last thing would be some thing like this , I was thinking this too But wanted to know that if it is possible do by other way

Comment: @CoasMckey you can calculate this value depends on screen size as well. But IMHO it is better to use thinks, that platform provides you) Especially with screen sizes in Android.

Comment: IMO this still feels a bit ridiculous since HTML/CSS can do it trivially and in a way that scales to sizes you aren't expecting.