# How to create gridview for tablet and phone screen size?

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I search and refer from Google and on this website. But I don't get correct answer for my problems. In my phone screen size, grid view is ok. But for tablet screen size, grid view are deranged.

code of gridview.xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp">
```

code of MainActivity.java

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

code of ImageAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 210));
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

[Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n21ZT.jpg) / [Tablet Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW8pb.png)

Comment: Make the folder layout-large for the tablet and set the gridview accordingly.

Comment: I do column_count; like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518265/grid-view-auto-number-of-columns-depending-on-screen-size. It doesn't change nothing

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Please share the Screenshot so i can figure it out..@StevenLin

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view is more powerful. You can try it with GridLayoutManager.

Check here.

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/